# Add Condition for ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on Imgur API and I fetched some image links. In a gridview, i am showing all pictures but sometimes api gives ".gif" and picasso cannot load this animated pictures. I want to pass if its a gif which convertview didn't load. As you can see, I'dont want to that gray areas. Do you have any idea?

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView ) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_image, parent, false);
    }
    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.im);
    if(datas.get(position).getLink().endsWith(".jpg") ){
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(datas.get(position).getLink())
                .fit()
                .into(img);
    }else convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return convertView;
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwozo.jpg): [[image: I'dont want to white gray areas]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove all objects which ends with .gif from the datas ArrayList, or you must not add them in the first place, you can give a condition  while adding in ArrayList

```
if(data.getLink().endsWith(".jpg"))
    datas.add(data)
```

Comment: Oh, its a simple solution thank you :) I couldn't think this.